# Javascript is concating or appending instead of adding

Tags: javascript

javascript function:

```
//from javascript file1
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      setContent(i);
   }

//from javascript file2 where function is present
        setContent: function (content) {    
        var xy=0;
        xy = parseInt(xy + content);
        console.log(xy);
```

Above code is appending the content instead of adding

Comment: The code you provided doesn't do what you claim. I'm sure you're passing a string instead, but you should take time to review the code you provide instead of just assuming it represents the problem you're having.

Comment: Your sample code works as expected. Provide more details please.

Answer (score 0):

do,

```
xy = xy + parseInt(content);
```

instead of,

```
xy = parseInt(xy + content);
```

as by doing this xy is concatenated first then is parsed to integer